# Edit files remotely on Windows Server 2012 with Python

Tags: python, windows, file-io, remote-access

How can I can connect remotely to a dedicated server with Windows Server 2012 R2 and edit or add files in `C:/Users/$user/AppData/Roaming`?

I prefer to do this in Python if there is any solution.

Answer (score 2):

In order to open the file on the remote server, use the UNC path:

```
fname = r'\\server_name\C$\Users\user_name\AppData\Roaming\file.txt'
with open(fname, 'r') as f:
    ...
```

Once you've opened the file, it's just like working with a file on your local file system.  The one caveat is that you **must** be running your script from an account that has the appropriate privileges on the remote server.  I usually do this by running it from a command prompt that I've opened as a user with elevated privileges.

I've used this method to do batch updates to hundreds of servers at a time.